# Reverse Array result error

Tags: java, arrays

The result from this code should be "In reverse order : any 10 numbers that user put" but I keep getting "in reverse order num In reverse order num In reverse order num ...." How can I change this? And also is there any possibility to change `public void reverseNumbersWhile (int num[])` method to `public void reverseNumbersWhile (int num)`? I added screenshot for more detail.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReverseNumbersFor
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
   ReverseNumbersFor reverse = new ReverseNumbersFor();
   reverse.setArray();
  } // end of main

  public void setArray()
  {
    int num [] = new int [10];
    reverseNumbersWhile(num);

  } 

    public void printArray (int num[])
    {
      for (int i = num.length - 1; i >=0; i--)
      {
        System.out.print("In reverse order : " + num[i] + " ");
      }
    }

    public void reverseNumbersWhile (int num[])
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter 10 numbers : ");

      int temp;
      int [] in = num;
      for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
      {
        in [i] = input.nextInt();
      }
      printArray(num);         
    }     
}
```

[image: Image of result]

Comment: Please learn the difference between Java and JavaScript.

Comment: The code pasted here is not even the same as in the picture.

Comment: it is the same code I just removed the comments and it's too long so the whole code did not fit in to the screen shot. I just wanted to people see the result that I getting in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit you print Array method as below,
the error is this  `result = (num[i] + " ");` it should be as `result += (num[i] + " ");` or if you like as `result = result + (num[i] + " ");`

simply you can write it as

```
public void printArray (int num[])
{
  for (int i = num.length - 1; i >=0; i--)
  {
    System.out.print(num[i] + " ");  

  }
}
```